# Find all composite type component types using WITH RECURSIVE

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-cte

Given the `typname` of a composite type, how do I find the type `oids` of all component types *recursively*?

Example:

```
CREATE TYPE t_station AS (x INT,
                          y INT,
                          label VARCHAR);

CREATE TYPE t_address AS (city VARCHAR,
                          street VARCHAR,
                          no INT,
                          stations t_station[]);

CREATE TYPE t_employee AS (name VARCHAR,
                           age INT,
                           coins INT[],
                           notes VARCHAR,
                           address t_address);
```

I can get the type `oids` of the members of `t_employee`:

```
SELECT
   t.typname, t.oid, a.attname, a.atttypid
FROM
   pg_attribute a INNER JOIN pg_type t ON a.attrelid = t.typrelid
   AND t.typname = 't_employee'
```

But I need to recurse that, which I guess can be done using `WITH RECURSIVE`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE allattrs(typname, oid, attname, atttypid) AS (
  select t.typname, t.oid, a.attname, a.atttypid from pg_attribute a inner join pg_type t on a.attrelid = t.typrelid and t.typname = 't_employee'
  union all
  select z.* from
  (select t.typname, t.oid, a.attname, a.atttypid from pg_attribute a inner join pg_type t on a.attrelid = t.typrelid) z,
  allattrs y where y.atttypid = z.oid
)
SELECT * FROM allattrs limit 100
;
```

But that does not find the inner array of `t_station` composite type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array types break the simple chain you are following. In case of an array type you have to resolve `pg_type.typelem` to get to the base type.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(typname, type_oid, attname, atttypid, typelem) AS (
   SELECT t.typname, t.oid, a.attname, a.atttypid, t.typelem
   FROM   pg_type t
   LEFT   JOIN pg_attribute a ON  a.attrelid = t.typrelid
                              AND a.attnum > 0
                              AND NOT a.attisdropped
   WHERE  t.typrelid = 't_employee'::regclass

   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.typname, t.oid
         ,COALESCE(a.attname, t.typelem::regtype::text)
         ,COALESCE(a.atttypid, t.typelem), t.typelem
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   pg_type t ON t.oid = c.atttypid AND (t.typtype = 'c' OR t.typelem > 0)
   LEFT   JOIN pg_attribute a ON  a.attrelid = t.typrelid
                              AND a.attnum > 0
                              AND NOT a.attisdropped
   )
SELECT typname, type_oid, attname, atttypid
FROM   cte
WHERE  typelem = 0  -- filter out rows for array types
```

If you want to include extra rows for array types in the result, remove the final WHERE condition ..

This JOIN condition only follows composite types or arrays:

```
AND (t.typtype = 'c' OR t.typelem > 0)
```

I also added conditions to exclude system columns and dead columns:

```
AND a.attnum > 0
AND NOT a.attisdropped
```

[Details about catalog tables in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalogs.html)

Comment: Ah, nice! Exactly what I needed. I just started using recursive CTEs and there is a learning curve .. but that PG feature really rocks!